# What is the ::before pseudo-element in the following code snippet doing?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

The code below is for a responsive flex circle example but I don't understand what the `.circle:before` is doing exactly and how it helped here? I thought the `::before` class would apply something in front of an element.

```css
.circle-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.circle {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  background: #bada55;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}
.circle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%; /* ratio of 1:1*/
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-wrap">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: Is this your code or someone else's?

Comment: Someone else's im looking at for an example i am trying to accomplish the same things with the circles.